# BreezeJS .toType error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: c#, .net, breeze

I'm using breezejs to query an IQueryable on the server.  The problem has come about because I have a Guid looking javascript string that on the server is a string and breezejs is interpreting the datatype of the javascript string as a Guid instead.  As I cannot change the server I have found where I should be able to use the .toType function to explicitly tell breeze the type for an endpoint query.

```
                var data = "e65ec82e-8b58-4a56-9c3f-a02a44d36045";
                var predicate = { "UserId": { "==": data } };
                var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('UserRoleApi/Search');
                if (predicate != null) {
                    query = query.where(predicate).toType('AspNetUserRole');
                }
                query = query.skip(page * pageSize).take(pageSize);

                breezeservice.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
```

This code gives me the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".  Without the .toType I get an error involving using an 'eq' between a guid and a string.  The 'AspNetUserRole' type is found and correct in the metadata.  Any help would be appreciated.

It appears my problem lies here in the breeze.js file.

```
if (newValue != null) {
      debugger;
    var siblings = newValue.getProperty(inverseProp.name);
    // recursion check if already in the collection is performed by the     relationArray
    siblings.push(parent);
  }
```

siblings is undefined.  Not sure if this is a breezejs bug.  Have to investigate more.

Now i've found if I have the commented code uncommented i get the error, otherwise I don't get an error and I get the correct response.  So the issue is not with the .toType but rather with breezejs recursively looking for siblings of entites.  It looks like it's looking for AspNetUserRole on Company and not finding it but not checking that siblings is not null or undefined and blowing up.  Company does not have a foreign key to AspNetUserRole so it should not find anything.  Seems like a breezejs bug to me.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<UserRoleViewModel> Search()
    {
        var response = repository.Search().Select(x => new UserRoleViewModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            UserId = x.UserId,
            RoleId = x.RoleId,
            CompanyId = x.CompanyId
            //Company = new CompanyViewModel()
            //{
            //    Id = x.Company.Id,
            //    Name = x.Company.Name
            //},
            //User = new UserViewModel()
            //{
            //    Id = x.AspNetUser.Id,
            //    UserName = x.AspNetUser.UserName
            //},
            //Role = new RoleViewModel()
            //{
            //    Id = x.AspNetRole.Id,
            //    Name = x.AspNetRole.Name
            //}
        });
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has to do with the fact that i'm returning a "UserRoleViewModel" but i was .toType('AspNetUserRole');  Obvious when i sit down and think about it.